# Paste in default textarea if no input is focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

When the user pastes anything and no input/textarea is focused on the page, I want the paste event to be handled by a specific default `textarea`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So listen for paste event. Determine if it is in an input. If it is not, read the clipboard data and do something with it.

```js
window.addEventListener("paste", function (evt) {
  if (!['TEXTAREA', 'INPUT'].includes(evt.target.nodeName)) {
    const clipboardData = evt.clipboardData || window.clipboardData
    const pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text')
    var ta = document.querySelector("textarea")
    ta.value = ta.value + pastedData
  }
})
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<input />
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Can I send the paste event to the textarea so that its value is automatically updated without having to access the clipboard APIs and manually updating it?